# Finding nearest value between Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I'm currently trying to generate a quartile map of a few key figures.

My quartiles are in a Pandas DataFrame looking like this:

```
                 0,05    0,1   0,25   0,33  
IndicatorName
indicator 1      10653  10512  10096   9857
indicator 2      2,85   2,87   3,01   3,11
indicator 3      1,66   1,75   1,84    1,9
indicator 4      13,01  11,78   8,55   7,64
```

This is a quartile mapping from a few hundred users
I then query my sql database and get values for One user and load this into a DF

```
                value
IndicatorName
indicator1      9917.00
indicator2      3.10
indicator3      1.86
indicator4      13.74
```

What I want to do now is to create a new column in my second DF containing an indication of which quartile the value lies within (nearest matching value):

```
                value     quartile
IndicatorName
indicator1      9917.00   0,33
indicator2      3.10      0,33
indicator3      1.86      0,25
indicator4      13.74     0,05
```

How would you go about comparing dataframes like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero step is replace `,` to `.` in `df1` and cast to `float`s.

```
df1 = df1.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Or:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file, decimal=',')
```

Also is necessary match indices, so if only difference is whitespaces, remove it:

```
df1.index = df1.index.str.replace('\s+','')
```

Then subtract column `value` by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), get [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) values and find column of minimal value by  [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
df2['quartile'] = df1.sub(df2['value'],axis=0).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
print (df2)
                 value quartile
IndicatorName                  
indicator1     9917.00     0,33
indicator2        3.10     0,33
indicator3        1.86     0,25
indicator4       13.74     0,05
```

Details:

```
print (df1.sub(df2['value'],axis=0))
                 0,05     0,1    0,25   0,33
IndicatorName                               
indicator1     736.00  595.00  179.00 -60.00
indicator2      -0.25   -0.23   -0.09   0.01
indicator3      -0.20   -0.11   -0.02   0.04
indicator4      -0.73   -1.96   -5.19  -6.10

print (df1.sub(df2['value'],axis=0).abs())
                 0,05     0,1    0,25   0,33
IndicatorName                               
indicator1     736.00  595.00  179.00  60.00
indicator2       0.25    0.23    0.09   0.01
indicator3       0.20    0.11    0.02   0.04
indicator4       0.73    1.96    5.19   6.10
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me out greatly. I had missed the decimal indicator in my csv import. the indicator names, were just standins for the true names, which of course are identical within the two DF's. Other than this I Now have data I can work on further.

Comment: You are welcome! And you can upvote my solution too. Thanks.